# Python - how to align using a variable as a value?

Tags: python

Im currently attempting to use right alignment to surrond a word chosen by the user in a box of a fixed length specified by the user. Below is my code thus far

```
# ask user to enter a name
user_input = input("Enter name: ")
name_input = user_input

#ask user to enter the length of the box
user_input = input("Enter the length of the box: ")
box_length = int(user_input)

#display the name in a box
print("Display the name in a box: ")
print("-" * box_length)
print("-{0}{1:>{box_length}} ".format(name_input,"-",box_length=box_length))
print("-" * box_length)
```

The expected output of this is as follows

```
Enter a name: frog
Enter the length of the box: 15
Display the name in a box:
---------------
-frog         -
---------------
```

However Im having an issue aligning the right hand side "-", having the following as my result

```
Enter name: frog
Enter the length of the box: 15
Display the name in a box: 
---------------
-frog              - 
---------------
```

As shown the right hand side "-" does not line up with the top and bottom as shown in the expected output and Im wondering as to why this is occuring

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You need to subtract the length of name from total length. `print("-{0}{1:>{box_length}} ".format(name_input ,"-",box_length=box_length-len(name_input)-1))`

Comment: What if you assign a string variable for the middle layer of the box like this: `middle_layer = "-" + name_input + " " * (box_length - 2 - len(name_input)) + "-"` and then just call `print(middle_layer)`

Comment: You can also measure the amount of spaces you need in your box excluding the name and the boxs' exterior first.

`
spaces = box_lenght - len(name_input) + 2

print(f'-{name_input}{" "*spaces}-')
`

Answer (score 0):

So I'm an amateur and a newbie when it comes to coding so I might be able to provide a very simple method.

One thing you could do is find the length of the name_input use this formula:

```
box_length - (len(name_input)+1) - 1
```

to give the number of spaces after the name_input and the hyphen at the very end. I add 1 to len(name_input) to consider the hyphen '-' at the beginning. My understanding is when you pass this line:

```
print("-{0}{1:>{box_length}} ".format(name_input,"-",box_length=box_length))
```

it is causing the output to have the number of spaces as defined in the variable box_length. So you can chnage that line as

```
print("-{0}{1:>{box_length}} ".format(name_input,"-",box_length=box_length - (len(name_input)+1) - 1))
```

Let me know if this works for you and if this was your query.